# when using two streams, data in the table is duplicated

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is such a code that takes data from api and puts it in the database. If you leave it as it is now, then the recorded data in the database is duplicated (with one call to the run_schedule_reg function). When I delete everything related to the second stream, the data is not duplicated. I don’t understand what the problem is.

```
import requests, time, datetime, json, schedule, sqlite3
from threading import Thread

conn = sqlite3.connect('parser.sqlite', check_same_thread = False)
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reg/'


def get_registers(date):
    full_page = requests.get(url, auth=("admin","admin"))
    pars=json.loads(full_page.content.decode('utf-8'))
    a=sorted(pars, key=lambda pars: pars['time_visit'])
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `register` (`time` STRING, `number_car` VARCHAR)")
        for i in a:
            if i['date_visit']==date:
                number_car=i["number_car"]
                time_visit=i["time_visit"]
                cursor.execute("insert into register values (?, ?)", (time_visit, number_car))
        conn.commit()
    cursor.close()

def run_schedule_reg():         
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_registers,date)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


def print_time_visit(time_now): 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `register`")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            index=2
            time_db=row[0][:index] + row[0][index+1:]
            time_now_to_int =time_now[:index] + time_now[:index]
            if abs(int(time_db) - int(time_now_to_int) ) < 30:
                print(row[0], row[1])
    cursor.close()  

def run_schedule_time():            
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_now = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(print_time_visit,time_now)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


thread1 = Thread(target=run_schedule_reg).start()
thread2 = Thread(target=run_schedule_time).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem locally. By adding additional `print`-statements I could see that `get_registers` sometimes was executed twice instead of once every few time units .

I think the problem is that you call `schedule.run_pending()` in two different threads. Why do you need two create threads anyhow? As long as your database queries take longer than a 5 minutes (which I highly doubt) your script should work just fine without them.

My proposed solution to your problem: Make sure you only call `schedule.run_pending` in the main thread. Additionally, remove your threads if possible.

```py
import datetime
import schedule
import time

def get_registers(date):
    print(f"get_registers {date} [{datetime.datetime.now()}]")


def run_schedule_reg():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(get_registers, date)
    # no schedule.run_pending() here!


def print_time_visit(time_now):
    print(f"print_time_visit {time_now}")


def run_schedule_time():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_now = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(print_time_visit, time_now)
    # no schedule.run_pending() here!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_schedule_reg()
    run_schedule_time()

    while True:
        print(".")
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

*(I changed the time unit from minutes to seconds for testing purposes)*

Please note that there might be a second bug that I did not address in my sample: I think you want to calculate the values for the variables `date` and `time_now` not in the functions `run_schedule_reg` and `run_schedule_time` but in the corresponding worker functions `get_registers` and`print_time_visit`. Otherwise these arguments are not going to update over time.